# How to fetch all the details of a marketplace organization's page on Drupal.org

Tags: community-official-site

I am new to Drupal.
I am trying to fetch all the details of a marketplace organisation's page, which are visible on drupal.org.

I am using the node id to access "https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node/xxxxxxx.json" (where "xxxxxxx" is the node id).

I am not getting all the data in the response.

Is there any way to fetch all the data of a particular page in json?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with GET method with your URL.

GET https://www.drupal.org/api-d7/node/782.json

Comment: I am trying the same ,
but I am not getting all the data from that node .

Comment: Would you please inform or elaborate which all data you want?